# Free Highcharts Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, c#, charts

I made an ASP.NET MVC Project, where I use Highchart. The chart has columns and a line. Now the company I make this project for said, that they do not want to pay for a highchart license so I have to search for an alternative js chart library.
The requirements are:

- it should be for free
- it should be as similar as possible to highcharts
- i need a chart with columns and a line
- i need drilldown for "data zooming"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the list of charting libraries mentioned in [Charting libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#supportedlibraries), which are used as charting engines in various contributed [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) modules (disclosure: I'm the original author of this page).

These are my personal favorites (also because they are used in the Drupal modules I (co-) maintain):

- PHP SVG Graph
- pChart
- D3

Up to you to further investigate which of these libraries might possibly be considered as a valid alternative in your case. While investigating, make sure to also consider the actual license (open source, commercial, etc) for those libraries.